# How do I retrieve the amount of the count and update it on my second table row? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have for e.g table1 and table 2, in the table 1 I need to count how many times number 1 happens from the row Organizacao, then sum all up and update table 2 row cntVoluntarios.

In order to count I did this:

```
CREATE PROC CntVoluntarios
SELECT 'OrganizacaoID', COUNT(*) AS 'Voluntarios'
FROM Pessoa
WHERE 'OrganizacaoID'=1
```

But how can I now retrieve the amount of count and update it to table 2 row cntVoluntarios??

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help here.

Comment: Why would you create a SP for it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, I'm not sure if I got the fields correct... but you can adjust it to your needs

```
UPDATE table2
   SET cntVoluntarios = ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM Pessoa
              WHERE 'OrganizacaoID'=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE M
SET C_Name =S.Voluntarios
FROM Table_1 M
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrganizacaoID, COUNT(*) AS Voluntarios
FROM Pessoa
GROUP BY OrganizacaoID) S ON S.OrganizacaoID=M.OrganizacaoID
```

Hope this Works for your case:

Can u provide any sample data to check further?

Comment: It's like I want it to show how many volunteeers this company has currently
https://imgur.com/a/dVxilxr

Comment: Can u say what's the exact issue you are facing in the above query?@DaniSLB20

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Organizacao, COUNT(1) Cnt
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Organizacao
)
UPDATE T2
SET cntVoluntarios = Cnt
FROM Table2 T2
JOIN CTE T1 ON T1.Organizacao = T2.Organizacao
WHERE T1.Organizacao = 1;
```